# gcp - how to run Python application as Service Account without a key file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, impersonation, service-accounts

`gcloud` and `gsutil` have `--impersonate-service-account` by which we can impersonate a service account.

For Python program, is there a way to run the program as a service account without using the service account secret key file as key file is not recommended for security reason.

> Service account keys could pose a security risk if compromised. We recommend that you avoid downloading service account keys

Comment: Check out [`google-auth`](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/index.html) library's [impersonated_credentials](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.impersonated_credentials.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For Python program, is there a way to run the program as a service
> account without using the key file as key file is not recommended for
> security reason.

If your Python program is running outside Google Cloud, then no, you must use credentials.

You have a catch22. You need to be authorized using credentials to impersonate another credential.

You have three choices:

- user account credentials
- another service account credentials
- federated tokens

Each of those methods requires secrets.

For compute services, such as Compute Engine, Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, etc you can use the metadata service for authorization. However, then you do not need to impersonate credentials, you can just use the credentials as they are safe (no secrets stored on the machine).

I wrote an article on this topic and how to setup impersonation using user account credentials:

[Google Cloud – Improving Security with Impersonation](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-improving-security-with-impersonation/)

If impersonation is set up correctly, the flag **--impersonate-service-account** is not required.

Comment: Thanks John, I read https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-where-are-my-credentials-stored/ as well. Appreciate the articles you have written. If I may follow up, although Google recommend not to use Service account keys, there is no way to test python programs as a service account to make sure the python program runs with the service account?

Comment: Use case is to make sure the service account has proper permissions to run the python program which uses multiple GCP services. From my laptop outside GCP, I need a way to impersonate the service account to run the python program. But seems there is no way without using the service account key file, which is recommended not to use.

Comment: @mon - Do not over-interpret Google's recommendation. There are use cases where service accounts are required and other cases where they are not. You can use a service account with Python programs. You can use a service account to impersonate another service account. If your application is running outside the cloud, then you must use credentials. That means secrets of some form. In Google Cloud that is OAuth and sometimes API Keys. Well-implemented security is rarely just hard and fast rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to use a keyless authentication in your python program. It's called [Workload Identity Federation (WIF)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation).

With WIF you use an external **provider** to generate a [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) (OIDC) **identity token**. This external provider can be an IDaaS (IDentity as a Service) like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/), [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) or [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/), or it can be something you build yourself. More precisely, you would need to create an OAuth 2.0 [authorization server](https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/flask/2/authorization-server.html), for example using a library like [Authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib). I've never done it myself, but I'm sure it's a lot of work.

Once you have set up the external identity provider, you will need to [configure a workload identity pool](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workload-identity-federation#oidc):

> To allow the use of these tokens, you must configure the workload identity pool to trust your external identity provider. Tokens issued by the external identity provider are then recognized by workload identity federation, and you can use the tokens to obtain short-lived service account credentials.

Personally, I would think twice about implementing an OAuth 2.0 authorization server myself. I don't want to worry about issuing the correct type of token, and certainly I do not want to worry about managing the database of tokens (blacklisting them, invalidating them, etc). Most likely I would either download the JSON key of a service account and use it in my python program, or pay an IDaaS to use to issue ID tokens (i.e. the external identity provider used in Workload Identity Federation).

Comment: Workload Identity Federation federates tokens from one identity service into tokens from another identity service. Secrets (credentials) are still required. WIF is excellent for authenticating from another service that provides managed identity credentials  (AWS, Azure, GitHub, etc).

Comment: isn't configuring a workload identity pool and exchanging an ID token (issued by this external provider) for a short-lived access token (issued by GCP) enough?

Comment: How do you imagine the first token is created? That step requires credentials/secrets. Authorization and authentication cannot be sidestepped with Workload Identity Federation. Federation is the process of exchanging one set of credentials for another.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the heads up. I thought it was the other way around: 1. external provider issues an ID token; 2. identity pool accepts the tokens since it recognizes the issuer; 3. Security Token Service exchanges the ID token for a short-lived access token. I thought the credentials were required just for the first step, so they were credentials for the external provider, not for GCP.